# Global Menu for Komodo Edit/IDE in Ubuntu

Tags: globalmenu, komodo-edit

Komodo IDE/Edit uses the same source as Firefox so if Firefox has Global Menu there must be a way to do the same for Komodo also.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Komodo team have just added support for the Unity Global menu here:
http://community.activestate.com/node/9281

You can install it through Komodo's *Tools > Add-ons* dialog.

**Update for Komodo 8.0**

The above mentioned add-on will not work for Komodo 8 so try this:
http://community.activestate.com/node/9547

Comment: Yes I read the tweet and was going to answer my own question but you got it first :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the very last solution, for latest Komodo Edit/IDE (currently 8.5.4)
http://forum.komodoide.com/t/ubuntu-global-menu/65

Comment: Please provide a complete solution with steps instead of a link.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar why? The link points to a discussion, that can evolve and, of course, propose better solution than mine in the future.